What material is this bathroom sink made of?
I’ve encountered a sink in a public restroom that has a very distinct appearance, and I’m curious about the material used in its construction. The sink has a matte, concrete-like texture with small chips and imperfections visible on the surface.
I am not an expert, but I’m a hobbyist familiar with scagliola. I’ve made some small art pieces, and now I want to create something that has a similar texture but is more resistant to outdoor weather conditions. (Probably I am gonna try to put together a sink at home, but I am quite far from that in knowledge: but my enquiry is a start:).) However, I don’t have any experience in architecture or construction, so please explain things with that in mind.
Could you help me identify what material this sink is made of? I’ve included close-up images for reference.
Thank you for any guidance or insights you can offer!




It's concrete. Scagliola wouldn't work out too well for a sink. Lots of videos on YT detailing how to make a concrete countertop and/or sink. YMMV.

Do you want to replace it, or repair it?

It's a concrete sink. It's made with a form and pouring concrete on it. After the concrete hardens, the forms are removed and then the defects ground off. It gives a nice industrial look, which I like, but it's all about the context.

If the context is a paint-chips countertop from a 1970s shopping mall do you still like it?  :)

@jay613 Nostalgia is cool.
